# std::unique_ptr structure member to the structure type

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Is

```
struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
};
```

allowed by the standard? I don't think it is for container types like `std::set` but is there something *special* about `unique_ptr`?

Comment: It is rather an example of member of the same type. Making it point to itself would introduce a circular reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's explicitly allowed. C++14 (n4140) 20.8.1/5:

> ... The template parameter `T` of `unique_ptr` may be an incomplete type.

It is also allowed for `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`, using similar wording.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's allowed. This basically an implementation of some kind of *path*.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

According to this **[reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)**:

> std::unique_ptr may be constructed for an incomplete type T, such as
>   to facilitate the use as a handle in the Pimpl idiom. If the default
>   deleter is used, T must be complete at the point in code where the
>   deleter is invoked, which happens in the destructor, move assignment
>   operator, and reset member function of std::unique_ptr.

So yes `std::unique_ptr` can be used in this way.